# is there a way to pass data drupal site to java web applicatiom

Tags: java, drupal-6

Is there any way to pass an application form in drupal 6 site to java web application ?

My client asked me about this can we pass a data from an application form developed in drupal webform to java web application can any one help?

Comment: You can use query string and invoke a GET request on the server. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways of doing,

**Using `<form>`:** set your java web url in `action` attribute

```
<form name="app_form" method="post" action="YOUR_JAVA_WEB_URL">
  ...
  ...
</form>
```

**[Using CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):**

cURL allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of servers with many different types of protocols. Here's a sample code to send POST data to different server,

```
<?php    
  $ch = curl_init();

  $data = array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'age' => $_POST['age']);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOUR_JAVA_WEB_URL');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  curl_exec($ch);
?>
```